# Expand menu items to the max width bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a top navbar and some content in a html file. The problem is that the menu items are in the middle of the screen, just like in this simple representation:

%%%%item 1%%item 2%%item 3%%item 4%%item 5%%%%

where % represent space. When I put the content in the html, it doesn't get aligned neither in the left side or the right side with the navbar. For example, the text gets out of border in both sides, but just visually. The problem is that the menu items are some cells and the text inside is centered so it has some space in the left and right side and that's why the text in the html doesn't seem aligned when i'm using container. Is there a way to expand the items text to fill the max length of the cell or to fit the cells exactly to the size of the text, to solve the issue?

Please see the picture for a better understanding of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We are not mind readers, we cannot help you fix your code if you don't show it to us!

Comment: Well, I'm using a framework for this and the css has like 20.000 lines of code. I don't quite know how to isolate only the part that affects the navbar so I can post it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use https://jsfiddle.net/ to make sample of your code and embed link in your question.

Comment: Well without seeing it, we can't help - like I said, we're not mind readers, we can't magically tell whats causing problems in your code. Have you tried using the browsers element inspector to see the CSS that applies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposed that you use boostrap (but I am not a mind reader). And I hope to have understood correctly your problem.

If you use a predefined template proposed by boostrap you probably have something like this to represent your navbar:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

On the anchor tag there are default parameters set and you need to override these parameters if you want your own parameters. In your case you need to remove the left and right padding by setting it at 0px.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px" href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px" href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px" href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can create a css class to have a clearer code.

The result will be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRhjU.png)